# Keeping NSManagedObjects in multiple contexts synchronized

Tags: ios, core-data, nsmanagedobjectcontext

I need an advice for the following scenario. I have two managed object contexts in my app. Depending upon the thread they are accessed via same property i.e.

`self.managedObjectContext`

If any context changes or saves data i want to keep data sync on both contexts using

`-refreshObject:mergeChanges:`

and passing mergeChanges = YES, And the app is also listening for notification `NSManagedObjectContextDidSaveNotification`. But i cannot know which context saved data. (or can i? if yes, Can anybody tell?)

My question is that on receiving this notification should i perform `-refreshObject:mergeChanges:` on both contexts? e.g.

```
[bgContext refreshObject:self mergeChanges:YES];
[fgContext refreshObject:self mergeChanges:YES];
```

OR

```
[self.managedObjectContext refreshObject:self mergeChanges:YES];
```

or what approach should i follow?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your call to `NSNotificationCenter -addObserver:selector:name:object:`, provide the appropriate MOC as the `:object` parameter. Now you'll only receive notifications for changes from that MOC. The `object:` parameter works the same if you're using the blocks-based `addObserver:...` call.

You could also use just the notfication, without registering diffferent selecotrs/blocks per context. When the notification arrives, you can check its `object` property and use that to determine which context needs updating.